# Assign Taylor expansion to function

Tags: maxima, taylor-series

When I use **Maxima** to calculate the Taylor series:

```
f(x,y) := taylor((x+y)^3, [x, y], [2, 3], 2);
f(2,3);  /* error: wrong number of arguments */
```

Basically I want to define a function as a expansion of `(x+y)^3`, which takes in `x,y` as parameter.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: @stark I'm new to Maxima.  Could you give a full example?  Thanks.

Comment: Never mind.  I think you just need to set variable: PSEXPAND:MULTI

Comment: @stark Thanks.  But still `taylor: wrong number of arguments.
#0: f(x=2,y=3)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
(%i1) f(x,y) := ''(ratdisrep(taylor(('x+'y)^3, ['x, 'y], [2, 3], 2))) $

(%i2) f(2, 3);
(%o2)                                 125
```

or

```
(%i1) define(f(x, y), ratdisrep(taylor(('x+'y)^3, ['x, 'y], [2, 3], 2)))$

(%i2) f(2, 3);
(%o2)                                 125
```

Comment: Though I don't know what's going on here, this works.  I may need to dive into the Maxima manual for this.  Thanks.

Comment: @gongzhitaao Ordinarily the body of a function is not evaluated when the function is defined via `:=`. The reason that `f(x, y) := ''(...))` and `define(f(x, y), ...)` work is that they evaluate the body of the function (the Taylor expansion) at the time the function is defined.