# Maxima: evaluate a function f(x) embedding diff() nouns

Tags: maxima, differentiation, taylor-series

I generate a Taylor series following [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294656/assign-taylor-expansion-to-function) instructions :

```
f(x) := ''(ratdisrep(taylor(qExct('x),'x,0,5)));
```

qExct is a function that is not defined : I want to perform a certain computation for any qExct that is a smooth function.

Knowing this, how do I set variable `x` to a certain value (e.g. 1) ?

If I do this :

```
f(1);
```

Then maxima returns me the following error :

```
diff: variable must not be a number; found: 1
```

And if I do that :

```
f(D);
```

then it considers `D` a variable and substitutes all occurrences of variable `x` with variable `D`.  In particular, it differentiates using d/dD instead of d/dx. However, what I would like is to substitute variable `x` with number `1` in the x^n terms only and keep the derivatives as they are…

How do I do this ?

Comment: Actually, I do not know the definition of qExct in advance :  qExct could be virtually any smooth function. This is part of a script that generates numerical schemes. Writing the Taylor expansions is the first step, then I must make a linear combination of the Taylor series expansions to cancel out as many derivatives as possible. I shouldn't need the definition of qExct for this. Any idea ?

Comment: @FredSenese Actually, Maxima is pretty comfortable with undefined functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable in a `diff` expression is not recognized everywhere in Maxim as a dummy (formal) variable, so when you try to evaluate `f(1)`, Maxima substitutes 1 into the `diff` expression and causes the error. I think that's a bug; I'll make a bug report about it.

As a work around, you can use the add-on package `pdiff` (positional derivatives) which is included with Maxima. The notation is a little different from the dy/dx notation which is used by default in Maxima.

```
(%i1) load (pdiff) $
(%i2) f(x) := ''(ratdisrep(taylor(qExct('x),'x,0,2)));
                                    2
                     qExct     (0) x
                          ""(2)
(%o2)        f(x) := ---------------- + qExct     (0) x + qExct(0)
                            2                ""(1)
(%i3) f(h);
                                2
                   qExct   (0) h
                        (2)
(%o3)              -------------- + qExct   (0) h + qExct(0)
                         2               (1)
(%i4) ev (%, qExct=sin);
(%o4)                                  h
(%i5) ev (%o3, h=1);
                     qExct   (0)
                          (2)
(%o5)                ----------- + qExct   (0) + qExct(0)
                          2             (1)
```

I think the spurious `""` in the display of `f(x) := ...` are minor display bugs; I think you can ignore them.

There is documentation for `pdiff` in `share/pdiff/pdiff-doc.pdf` in your Maxima installation.

Comment: @RobertDodler both of your solutions are working, but `pdiff` is more suited to my case : I have many derivatives lying around, so a concise writing style is better. Didn't know about `pdiff` before, so thanks for that ! Thank you @RobertDodler @FredSenese for your time & answers !

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution, which uses `at` instead of `pdiff`.

```
(%i1) f(x) := ''(ratdisrep(taylor(qExct('x),'x,0,2)));
                                !
                   2            !
               2  d             !
              x  (--- (qExct(x))!     )
                    2           !
                  dx            !                         !
                                !x = 0       d            !
(%o1) f(x) := ------------------------- + x (-- (qExct(x))!     ) + qExct(0)
                          2                  dx           !
                                                          !x = 0
(%i2) at(f(x), x=1);
                           !
                     !     !
        2            !     !
       d             !     !
       --- (qExct(x))!     !
         2           !     !
       dx            !     !                           !
                     !x = 0!                     !     !
                           !x = 1   d            !     !
(%o2)  -------------------------- + -- (qExct(x))!     !      + qExct(0)
                   2                dx           !     !
                                                 !x = 0!
                                                       !x = 1
(%i3) %, qExct=sin;
                                !
                          !     !
               2          !     !
              d           !     !
              --- (sin(x))!     !
                2         !     !
              dx          !     !                         !
                          !x = 0!                   !     !
                                !x = 1   d          !     !
(%o3)         ------------------------ + -- (sin(x))!     !
                         2               dx         !     !
                                                    !x = 0!
                                                          !x = 1
(%i4) %, nouns;
(%o4)                                  1
```

Note that `f(1)` is evaluated via `at(f(x), x=1)`.

The nested `at` expressions are a nuisance; I've fixed it (in Maxima's source code) so that doesn't happen anymore.